# Firing many HTTP request through an IntentService

Tags: android

I have created an IntentService to send the data to the server. I have many tables in the server database and need to send the data to the tables. Each table has a different URL. How should I send the data to all the tables at once and then informing the user when all the data to all the tables has been sent. At the present I am sending data to only one table.
Thanks

Comment: Change the serverside implementation so you can hit one endpoint that will update all serverside data ("knowing it is tables is an implementation detail" .. which is bad)

Comment: @Pratishthasharma first of all you need to know all basics of HTTP:- post and get so you need to see some exclusive examples ..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using volley library.Using this library you can add http request in a queue because it is efficient too. For storing data in multiple tables you can use transactions .By using transaction we can create a job and in a job can define your queries.  You can write multiple queries inside a transaction and execute once. But one thing keep in mind if any query failed in the transaction then none of the other query will be executed and the whole process will be roll back and changes will not be made in any of the table.

Comment: Can you give me an example with the code if you have any